# Change Hash Value of URL from Android WebView

Tags: android, hash, webview

I want to append some hash value in **URL** from **`Android Webview`** without reloading it.

I have checked these two Links but did not find working.
 1. [Changing the Android Webview hash without reloading page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774923/changing-the-android-webview-hash-without-reloading-page)
 2. [Change Android webview content (hash) without reloading the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121999/change-android-webview-content-hash-without-reloading-the-url)